# Mysq- Conection how to set to be able to insert Arabic Text in to database

Tags: php, mysql

this is the config.php

```
<? 
define('DB_SERVER', 'loalhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'pass');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('mysql_set_charset','utf8');
define('mysql_query','SET NAMES utf8_persian_ci');

?
```

when i insert arabic or persian text into database the formate changes.
how i can keep the text in database as same formate of insert.

regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the character set is correct throughout your database. This means checking all 3 layers, database, table and column. Using `utf8` & `utf8_general_ci` will work for your arabic and persian text.

The below queries can be used to check the character set on each of the objects in your database, you can also check and change them easily in most GUI apps as well.

Column

```
SELECT character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = "YOUR_SCHEMA"
  AND table_name = "YOUR_TABLE"
  AND column_name = "YOUR_COLUMN";
```

Table

```
SELECT collations.character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.TABLES AS tables,
  information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY AS collations
WHERE collations.collation_name = tables.table_collation
  AND tables.table_schema = "YOUR_SCHEMA"
  AND tables.table_name = "YOUR_TABLE";
```

Database (Schema)

```
SELECT default_character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE schema_name = "YOUR_SCHEMA";
```