# Arabic Text In MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a small problem. Mysql supports arabic right. When i store data in tables it's alright and everything works fine, but when i issue an sql to retrieve data. I get the arabic text as ???? marks. I have changed the charset of the tables and of the columns but still the same problem. I am using node express framework.

Comment: Just confirm that all your tables and columns [have the correct character set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774765/mysq-conection-how-to-set-to-be-able-to-insert-arabic-text-in-to-database/23774945#23774945). How are you displaying the data retrieved? If it's an HTML page, be sure to set the correct encoding for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the connection file of node withe express framework

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var db_config = {
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: '',
charset: 'utf8'
 };
 function handleDisconnect() {
connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since

// the old one cannot be reused.
connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
        console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
        setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
});                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
// If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
        handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
        throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
    }
});
}
 handleDisconnect();
 var sql1 = "SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
 connection.query(sql1, function (err, result) {
 var sql = "SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci";
 connection.query(sql,  function (err, result) {
 });
 });
```

Comment: Oh, yes, You have modified my given code, at the bottom. Don't forget to vote my answer up. Thanks @Gurpinder

Comment: Thanks alot. May god bless you too. thanks for your help and blesingd

Comment: @Muhammad Ashikuzzaman now i faced a problem for storing emojis or arabic character  after implement your code any idea you have?. Blank is stored in database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54173/discussion-between-gurpinder-and-muhammad-ashikuzzaman).

Answer (score 1):

For Collation of that column of the  table use `utf8_czech_ci`. And use this below code at the end of your database connection. If there have similar like this portion of code then replace that portion with below code.

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')or die('charset problem:'.mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'") or die('collation   problem:'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: That is Javascript code. But try to find the database connecion code in some php file or code portion. @Gurpinder

Comment: The problem is still remains. 5ITW1396546906515-????-??-??T??:??:??Zuvroixtyrs.jpeg fetched but 5ITW1396546906515-٢٠١٤-٠٤-٠٣T٢٠:٤١:٣٨Zuvroixtyrs.jpeg stored in database

Comment: I use the above query for node but nothing happens.

Comment: Try to find some thing like this code mysql_connect(.....),mysql_select_db(....) and at the last of that file use my given code.

Comment: why these queries run below my database connection?

Comment: because you need to set the Unicode format by Collation and Again when you have to fetch that data in Unicode format you need to use the given query.

Comment: Thank you too, May Allah Bless you.Please don't forget to vote up my answer. And can you show me your code, I am curious to see.Because I did not see the whole code but could dream the problem.@Gurpinder

Comment: You deselect the answer.